# Unity scrollview can't scroll to the end

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have a scrollview.Horizontal and vertical scrollbars are removed because it is ugly and I have space constraint.

When I populate items into content of the scrollview as shown in the image
[image]

I can't scroll. The view is moving but doesn't scroll.
When  I scroll, just scroll to some extent and scroll back to the original position.

What could be wrong?

[image]

Comment: You can't scroll because the scrolling is limited by the height/width of the `Content` object's actual size...which is *not* computed from its contents: you have to do that yourself or use a [`ContentSizeFitter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-ContentSizeFitter.html)

Comment: You mean I need to set in the property?

Comment: You want the height to change based on the content? Yes... Yes you do.

Comment: Thank you.Let me try. Yes to change based on the content.

Answer (score 10):

1. Check if you have Vertical checkbox enabled on Scroll Rect component.
2. On your content object after adding [ContentSizeFitter](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-ContentSizeFitter.html), you need to select either Min Size or Preferred Size to make the scroll view content automatically resize. The unconstrained option doesn't drive the height so your scroll view won't scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `Height` parameter in the `Content` object is not equal to zero:

[image]

What happens when you press play:

[image]

Now let's set `Height` to something much bigger than zero:

[image]

Here is what we get when we press play this time:

[image]

(The scroll bar appeared!)

Credit: [Unity scrollview can't scroll to the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47718326/unity-scrollview-cant-scroll-to-the-end#comment82397149_47718326)

Answer (score 0):

I also had that problem and got it fixed by adding a `Graphic Raycaster` component to my element that had the `Canvas` component (the parent element to the `Scroll View`).